# Lifecycle of controllers in Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Swing application and I have created subclasses of JPanels, JDialogs etc. and I have created an own controller for each.

Example:

```
UserRegistrationDialog has a UserRegistrationDialogController
```

I use an instance of this user registration controller in another controller which handles the whole JFrame. The user registration dialog controller shows the dialog when the user clicks a button in the JFrame.

My question is: Should I create a new controller object each time the user clicks the button? Or should I create the controller on startup of the main controller and then invoke a showDialog method etc. on it that displays the dialog? And should the JDialog view instance be created each time or be retained by the controller? So the question is related to the lifecycle/scope of subcontrollers and views.

Comment: I'd create only one instance valid during whole apps life_cycle,

Comment: both controller and view? or re-instantiate a new view for the controller on each click?

Comment: my question just about logics a) for why reason to create a new Registration twice if is used only one time, b) or/and why re_creating anything that is designated as input form used routinelly

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be create a singleton object of your controller so that a single object of your controller will be available throughout the application.